# linking to boost regex in gcc

Tags: c++, regex, boost, linker, boost-regex

i am trying to compile my program which uses regex on linux. I built the boost library in the
    libs/regex/build
by typing
    make -fgcc.mak
which created a directory gcc which contains the following four files

```
boost_regex-gcc-1_35
boost_regex-gcc-d-1_35
libboost_regex-gcc-1_35.a
libboost_regex-gcc-d-1_35.a
```

Now I want to use regex from my program which is in some arbitrary directory. 
I #included boost/regex.hpp

I got the error which stated that regex.hpp is not found. Then I gave the -I option in the g++ compiler. I didn't get that error.
But I get the following error

```
undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
```

I googled and found that I need to somehow link one of the above 4 libraries to my program. How can I do it. Which one should I link and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either add `libboost_regex-gcc-1_35.a` to your list of object files in your link step or add `-static -lboost_regex-gcc-1_35` to the same. Also be sure that you have an `-I` switch pointing to your boost includes directory in your compile step. If the libraries are outside the typical search path (`/usr/lib` on *nix), add that directory to your link command with `-Wl,-L/path/to/boost/libs` for `g++` or simply `-L/path/to/boost/libs` on `ld`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problems when using boost filesystem. Here's what I needed to do to get it to link statically.

Excerpt from My Original (problematic) Makefile:
LIBS = -static -lboost_filesystem

Solution:
LIBS = -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -Wl,-Bdynamic

You can view the complete Makefile from 
http://code.google.com/p/neptuner/source/browse/codebase/trunk/stratego/uboat/Makefile

Needed to add boost_system to make it link properly. Direct addition/specification of libboost*.a created more problems. Note the -Bdynamic is present to prevent static link of standard libraries.