# Why does order in which input libraries are specified matter?

Tags: linux, linker, ld

I'm quite new to programming for Linux. You could say I'm a Windows guy. So, I was porting my project to Linux, and it almost made me insane: I'm sure I have specified all the dependencies with -l flag, and yet I'm getting "unresolved symbol" errors.
Then I've found this topic, and it solved my problem: [Boost linking on Linux with GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862791/boost-linking-on-linux-with-gcc)

Could someone please explain me why does the order matter, and how exactly it matters? I'm pretty sure it is not the case with MSVC linker...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example will let you see why one-pass Unix linkers care about order.

Suppose you have main.o (generated by main.cpp) and libraries libx.a (no dependencies) and **liby.a ( depends on libx called newRefX)**.

If the linker goes in this order, you are fine as the linker goes from 1 to 3:

1. main.o refX=undef, refY=undef
2. **liby.a** refX=undef, refY=def,   **newRefX=undef**
3. libx.a refX=def,   refY=def,   **newRefX=def**

But if the linker goes in this order, you run into problems with newRefX:

1. main.o refX=undef, refY=undef
2. libx.a refX=def,   refY=undef,
3. **liby.a** refX=def,   refY=def,   **newRefX=undef**

So, you can see that you want the lowest level library (the one that depends on no others) last.

Answer (score 5):

From "[An Introduction to GCC - for the GNU compilers gcc and g++](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_18.html)"

> The traditional behavior of linkers is to search for external functions from left to right in the libraries specified on the command line. This means that a library containing the definition of a function should appear after any source files or object files which use it.

I believe that msvc linkers do 2 passes over the code so they might be able to resolve the symbols even when the libraries are specified in different order (reference missing ...)

Answer (score 2):

It is the way the Unix linkers work, since long time ago... See [Levine's book](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)